# Is this the fastest way to build dict?

Tags: python, performance, list, dictionary

I am reading an element list from an `xml` file and make the data into 2 dictionaries.

Was this the fastest way? (I don't think this is the best, you guys always surprise me.;-)

```
ADict = {}
BDict = {}
for x in fields:
    key = x.get('key')
    ADict[key] = x.find('A').text
    BDict[key] = x.find('B').text
```

I think add it one by one is a bad idea, but write it in a single line. aka more pythonic way like this

```
 ADict,BDict = [dict(k) for k in zip(*([(x.get('key'),x.find('A').text),(x.get('key'),x.find('B').text)] for x in fields))]
```

I don't think it's better, two reasons,
first, `x.get('key')` was called twice
second, create too much temp tuples

Comment: Your first way is fine. There's no reason to cram things into one line if they make more sense on many.

Comment: the second way isn't more pythonic because it uses more advanced features, it's less because it loses out on readability

Comment: Just being on a single line is not [pythonic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58968/what-defines-pythonian-or-pythonic).

Comment: xml file and fast don't really go together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not tested, but should work

```
ADict = dict((x.get('key'), x.find('A').text) for x in fields)
BDict = dict((x.get('key'), x.find('B').text) for x in fields)
```

Comment: Use `{x.get('key'): x.find('A').text for x in fields}`, It works in Python >= 2.7